# Express server not allowing CORS even though I'm using Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, cors, serverless

The browser error shows:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at <https://dev-api.mydomain.net/auth/login> from origin 'https://dev.mydomain.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also tried using my actual specific domain 'https://dev.mydomain.net'as the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value, and it didn't work, as well as trying the key 'origin' as well.

How can I get the server to accept requests from my domain?

```
import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import router from '../../routes'

const restServer = express()

restServer.use(cors({
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}))

restServer.use('', router)

export default restServer
```

Comment: I don't think that's an appropriate configuration for the CORS middleware, did you look at the examples on https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors? If you know the origin (and aren't writing this for third-party consumption), why do you *want* to set `*`?

Comment: I tried setting it to the exact origin. I was just trying any configuration to get it to work.

Answer (score -1):

```
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

// * Logging middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// * CORS headers setter
app.use(cors());
```

Use it like this, No need to set Manually 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' While using CORS Module!